# No Classic API Credential on Sandbox Test Account Linked with REST API apps

Tags: api, rest, paypal, credentials

**UPDATE**: If I create a new sandbox account, the Classic API stayed there even after I linked an REST API app to the account. Feels like old sandbox account moved from old sandbox website doesn't have Classic API?

It seems like the sandbox test account that belongs to a REST API apps doesn't have Classic API credentials (user, password, signature). It shows REST API credentials instead (ClientID, secret).

However, I can create another business sandbox account and that account will have Classic API credentials.

I wonder if I can use both on live endpoint? And possibly in sandbox too?

I use REST API to process customers' order payment while using Classic API's Mass Payment to distribute commissions to our affiliates.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the classic credentials( API username / PWD/ Signature) as well as the REST credentials( Client ID / Secret) at the same time . There is no restriction on having the both type of credentials on the same account both in live as well as sandbox account .

Make sure that the sandbox account for which there is no classic credentials is a verified account as this can also be the reason .